# Getting value from database

Tags: php, mysql

I want get the value from database, because I need that value to sum it with other value and I cant take it. Here is an example of what I need:

```
user_id    task_progress
1              2
3              4
5              6
```

I used

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT task_progress FROM dotp_tasks WHERE (user_id = '3')"); 
$result = mysql_fetch_array($check);
```

And it should echo 4 but it echo Array. What am I doing wrong? And after that can I normally make this

```
$new=$value + $result;
```

Comment: start by removing the brackets for `WHERE (user_id = '3')` that's only used for subqueries. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html

Comment: why not make use of mysql's aggregate functions http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx ?

Comment: also you should be using mysqli or PDO for your database stuff. mysql_ functions are old and deprecated since PHP 5.5.

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: msql_fetch_array returns an array. Try echo $result[0];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change your code to the following this should be what your looking for:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT task_progress FROM dotp_tasks WHERE user_id = '3'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($check);

$new=$value + $result[0];
```

By accessing the array first key you should get the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

`$result = mysql_fetch_array($check)` is an array and you cannot echo an array. As an array you can get the element by using `[Number_of_the_col]` or `['Name_of_the_col']`

In you case use :
`echo $result[0]; // echo the first element`